# Como comparar duas colunas distintas em excel e verificar se os dados de uma estão dentro de outra?

Tags: microsoft-excel, if, procv

Se puderem me ajudar nesse caso, ficaria bem grato. Estou tentando fazer uma coluna com o filtro de comparação entre duas colunas do excel, retornando o valor que são comuns às duas colunas.
Segue um pequeno exemplo:

```
Planilha 1       Planilha 1
Coluna A         Coluna B          Função
1213             4896                -
1212             4548                -
4546             3415                -
6768             1212               1212
4578             1213                -
...              ...                ...
```

Estou tentando na célula C1:

```
=PROCV(A1;B:B;2;FALSO)
```

Mas está dando o erro #REF!

Gostaria dessa FUNÇÃO pra fazer esse filtro e me retornasse o resultado na Coluna C.
Obs.: são milhares de dados em ambas as colunas.

Comment: Sua matriz só tem uma coluna, quando deveria ter no mínimo duas, e além disso você quer referenciar a segunda coluna (terceiro parâmetro = 2). Talvez a função CORRESP possa atender a suas necessidades: `CORRESP(A1; B:B; 0)`.

Comment: Valeu anonimo, consegui fazer pelo PROCV mesmo. Estava errando em um pequeno detalhe. Utilizei a ajuda do Robson Silva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está especificando que a matriz de dados para consulta é apenas a coluna `B`, e você pede para retornar a coluna de índice 2 da matriz de dados. Entretanto como sua matriz é apenas a coluna `B`, ocorre este erro, troque o número do índice de referencia da coluna para 1

```
=PROCV(A1;B:B;1;FALSO)
```

Você disse que os dados esta em planilhas diferentes, atente-se em selecionar as colunas da planilha correta para obter o resultado esperado